# How to add an Array of Object in a C# List<T>

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net

I have to create something like the below, a JSON string:

```
{
     "sync": {
          "email": "dummy@dummy.com",
          "first": "James",
          "last": "Dawson",
          "cell": "2120980989",
          "valueOfField": [
               {
                    "number": "1",
                    "content": "second"
               },
               {
                    "number": "10",
                    "content": "Y"
               }
               /* more as needed */
          ]
    }
}
```

I can do everything up to `valueOfField`.

Here is my code:

```
sync cu = new sync();
cu.first = "James";
cu.last = "Doe";
cu.email = "jdoe@goesnowhere.com";
cu.cell = "999-999-9999";
/*for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    cu.valueOfField.Add("1", "106-93-0909");
    cu.valueOfField.Add("5", "12/3/1995");
}*/
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { sync = cu });
...
public class sync
{
    public string first;
    public string last;
    public string email;
    public string cell;
    /*public IDictionary<string, string> valueOfField;*/
}
```

I tried adding an `IDictionary` but that didn't work.

Can I get some help in creating the `valueOfField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need another class for the valueOfs

```
public class ValueOf{
  public string number {get;set;}
  public string content {get;set;}
}
```

then

```
public class sync
{
    public string first;
    public string last;
    public string email;
    public string cell;
    public List<ValueOf> valueOfField = new List<ValueOf>();
}
```

now

```
   cu.valueOfField.Add(new ValueOf{
         Number="1", Content = "106-93-0909"
   });
   cu.valueOfField.Add(new ValueOf{
         Number = "5", Content = "12/3/1995"); 
   });
```

Comment: Thank you... The example topped off the answer! Appreciate it. IT all maks sense, drew a blank for a bit :) +1

Comment: I get a `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` error in those example... Don't I have to initialize the list?

Comment: @Si8 yes sorry see edit

Comment: I just did it during the population of values... but your works as well. Either or works. :)